# force graph in d3.js - disappearing nodes

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm trying to construct a directed force graph in d3.js that has a click listener on it that changes the the underlying data and redraws the graph. I belive I'm following Mr. Bostock's update pattern, but the issue that I'm having is that when I run the update triggered by the click listener the nodes disappear off the bottom of the screen leaving the links and labels behind.

This update seems to run, updates the existing nodes (turns them green in this case) then ignores the "enter" and "exit" sections (which is the desired behaviour) then hits the tick() function which send the nodes south.

I can get this working by removing the "g" tag on the node and thus decoupling the labels and the node, which is obviously not desirable.

I can't help feeling I'm missing something obvious! Or perhaps I should be tacking this a different way?

Here's the code:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    links,
    nodes,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-200)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("test.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  update();
});

function update() {
  nodes = root.nodes
  links = root.links

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

    svg.append("svg:defs").append("marker")
        .attr("id", "end")
        .attr("refX", 15)
        .attr("refY", 2)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 4)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L8,2 Z");

  // Update the links…
  //link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.name; });
  link = link.data(links)

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Update the nodes…
  node = svg.selectAll("g").select(".node").data(nodes, function(d) { return d.name; });


  node.style("fill", "green")

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("g")
      .append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("id", function(d) {return "node" + d.index; })
      .attr("r", 12)
      .style("fill", "#BBB")
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("svg:text")
      .attr("dx", 16)
      .attr("dy", ".15em")
      .attr("class", "nodelabel")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

}


function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {

    // DO ANYTHING
    update()
  }
}
```

and the contents of test.json is:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"name" : "John"},
    {"name" : "Alison"},
    {"name" : "Phil"},
    {"name" : "Jim"},
    {"name" : "Jane"},
    {"name" : "Mary"},
    {"name" : "Joe"}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source":  1, "target":  0},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  3, "target":  0},
    {"source":  4, "target":  0},
    {"source":  5, "target":  1},
    {"source":  6, "target":  1}
  ]
}
```

Comment: The force layout doesn't allow you to reset the nodes and links. To change them, set them once and then modify the underlying data structures. Do not call `force.nodes()` or `force.links()` several times.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. However if I move that chunk outside of the update() function I still have the same problem.

Comment: You also have to do the selection again inside `update()` -- your variable `link` contains the result of executing the selection.

Comment: another good spot. Changing that line to link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(links) doesn't have any effect though. I'm not actually changing the underlying data.

Comment: Wait, if you're not changing the data, what do you want to update?

Comment: Ah, poorly worded response from me. I will be changing the underlying data but I'm not in the example.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. Are you saying that your old data and new data aren't matched up correctly?

Comment: So for the purposes of demonstrating the problem I've left out the bit that changes the data. The update section actually work exactly as expected using the code above. But after it runs the vectors of the node are set to some place off screen by the tick() function. It maybe be a problem with the data, but since the data is not changed I can't see how.

Comment: You may want to `.restart()` the force layout instead of `.start()`.

Comment: is restart a function? like force.restart()? Doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `.resume()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I figured out the problem. When I was selecting the nodes to update I was selecting the nodes (that is, the elements that had the class "node") and they were being updated:

```
node = svg.selectAll("g").select(".node").data(nodes, function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Then in the tick function I was updating those nodes:

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

so that was quite right, however, the nodes were encapsulated in the "g" tag along with the text label, but the `tick()` function was only acting on the node. The fix was to force the transform attribute in `tick()` to update the whole group rather than just the node:

```
svg.selectAll("g").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

All works now!